# How to unit-test Spark Streaming code in Java

Tags: java, apache-spark, spark-streaming

`JavaStreamingContext.queueStream()` Javadoc states:

> Changes to the queue after the stream is created will not be recognized

Therefore, using a queue for testing window based scenarios in Java is not an option, as opposed to Scala, because elements must be added to the queue in a certain rate while Spark is consuming it.
How can this be achieved without resorting to ugly workarounds, except using files or sockets?